# BubbleUp method in Heap implementation in c

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, heap

I posted my heap implementation here earlier and got some much needed help with my add() function, which I'm beyond grateful for, but I'm still getting invalid reads and memory leaks, and could use further assistance.

heap.h header file:

```
#ifndef HEAP_H
#define HEAP_H
#include <stdbool.h>
struct Entry {
  int key;
  char* value;
};

typedef struct Entry Entry;

struct Heap {
  int capacity;
  int size;
  Entry** elements;
};

typedef struct Heap Heap;

Heap* makeHeap(int capacity);
void add(Heap* heap, int priority, char* value);
char* removeMin(Heap* heap);
char* peek(Heap* heap);
int size(Heap* heap);
void cleanupHeap(Heap* h);

#endif
```

heap.c file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "heap.h"

Heap* makeHeap(int capacity) {
   //Make the heap
   Heap* theHeap = calloc(1, sizeof(Heap));
   //set its capacity to param
   theHeap->capacity = capacity;
   //inital size is 0
   theHeap->size = 0;
   //elements contains pointers (references) to Entry objects.
   theHeap->elements = calloc(capacity, sizeof(Entry*));
   //iterate capacity times allocating an entry reference for each element to be placed
   int i = 0;
   for(; i < capacity; i++) {
     theHeap-> elements[i] = calloc(1, sizeof(Entry));
   }

   return theHeap;
}

void expandCapacity(Heap* h) {
   Entry** oldcontents = h->elements;
   Entry** newarr = calloc(h->capacity * 2, sizeof(Entry*));
   int i = 0;
   for(; i < h->size; i += 1) {
      newarr[i] = h->elements[i];
   }

   h->capacity = h->capacity * 2;
   h->elements = newarr;
   free(oldcontents);
}

void add(Heap* h, int priority, char* val) {
  if (h->size >= h->capacity) {
    expandCapacity(h);
  }
  //insert at end of storage array and bubble up
  Entry* toAdd = calloc(1, sizeof(Entry));
  toAdd->key = priority;
  toAdd->value = val;
  h->elements[h->size]=toAdd;
  h->size += 1;
  bubbleUp(h, h->size);
}

void bubbleUp(Heap* h, int index) {
   if(index <= 0) { return; }
   Entry* e = h->elements[index];
   Entry* parent = h->elements[(index-1)/2];
   int comp = strcmp(e->value, parent->value);
   if(comp > 0) {
     swap(h, index, parent->key);
     bubbleUp(h, parent->key);
   }
   else {
     return;
   }
}

void swap(Heap* h, int index1, int index2) {
   Entry* tmp = h->elements[index1];
   h->elements[index1] = h->elements[index2];
   h->elements[index2] = tmp;
}
void cleanupHeap(Heap* h) {
   int i = 0;
   for (; i < h->capacity; i++) {
      free(h->elements[i]);
   }
   free(h->elements);
   free(h);
}
```

bubbleUp() and swap() were given functions in Java, so all I had to do was adapt them for this project to work with the heap.h file, and of course translate them to c. I'm confident in add() from my earlier assistance, and swap() also as it seems pretty straightforward, but I'm thinking there's an issue with my translation to c for bubbleUp(). Any input is greatly appreciated.

Java Code:

```
 void bubbleUp(int index) {
    if(index <= 0) { return; }
    Entry<K,V> e = this.entries.get(index);  
    Entry<K,V> parent = this.entries.get(parent(index));  
    int comp = this.comparator.compare(e.key, parent.key);
    if(comp > 0) {
      swap(index, parent(index));
      bubbleUp(parent(index));
    }
    else {
      return;
    }
}

void swap(int i1, int i2) {
    Entry<K,V> tmp = this.entries.get(i1);
    this.entries.set(i1, this.entries.get(i2));
    this.entries.set(i2, tmp);
}
```

Test:

```
#include "cutest/CuTest.h"
#include "heap.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void TestAdd(CuTest *tc) {
  Heap* h = makeHeap(10);
  add(h, 4, "lol");
  CuAssertIntEquals(tc, 1, h->size);
  cleanupHeap(h);
}

CuSuite* StrUtilGetSuite() {
  CuSuite* suite = CuSuiteNew();
  SUITE_ADD_TEST(suite, TestAdd);
  return suite;
}

// Don't edit below this line

void RunAllTests(void) {
  CuString *output = CuStringNew();
  CuSuite* suite = CuSuiteNew();
  CuSuite* ourSuite = StrUtilGetSuite();

  CuSuiteAddSuite(suite, ourSuite);

  CuSuiteRun(suite);
  CuSuiteSummary(suite, output);
  CuSuiteDetails(suite, output);
  printf("%s\n", output->buffer);

  CuStringDelete(output);
  CuSuiteDelete(suite);
  free(ourSuite);
}

int main(void) {
  RunAllTests();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: How's the Java code? Perhaps it's the *expandCapacity* that is wrong, who knows. Please produce a proper [mcve] that is a minimal runnable program that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @Atti Hapaala My apologies. I have added the missing functions.

Comment: Should emphasize *minimal*...

Comment: Your java code excerpt has "bubble down"

Comment: Also, instead of `calloc`ing and copying, you should `realloc`

Comment: @Atti Hapaala *sigh* really making myself look great here.. Please excuse me for that.

Comment: If this is a translation exercise, you should keep each word as close as possible to the original code. You are currently mixing `index`, `key` and `value`, which cannot be correct. The Java code compares keys while the C code compares values.

Comment: @Rolland Illig due to the Java project and the heap implementation I'm currently working on being defined quite differently, I had to change the C code to compare values, which are char* arrays (Strings in C to my knowledge) derived from the Entry struct. I think this is comparable to the key in the Java example which was also a String. The Java code was a bit strange in that its keys were Strings.

Comment: I still don't get why do you have a *heap* with *integer priority* but you organize it by a *string* - what's the meaning of that *priority* anyway

Comment: Which `CuTest` suite are you using? The one from SourceForge or one of the ones on GitHub? You code will not compile until you add `bubbleUp` and `swap` to `heap.h` (or refactor order of functions). There is no `cleanupHeap(h);`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I am not sure which version it is, it was included with the assignment and the license nor readme state which the version unfortunately. The program has been compiling without the added methods in heap.h, and I've updated the code to show cleanupHeap()

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I believe I have made a grave mistake. We are supposed to order by the keys, not the char* array values of the Entry Struct.

Comment: That's what I thought. In any case the *primary* mistake was the one that is in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The translation is not *close enough*. In Java you have `parent(index)`. In C you've inlined it as `(index-1)/2`. **This is what needs to go as the argument into the other functions**:

```
swap(h, index, (index-1)/2);
bubbleUp(h, (index-1)/2);
```

Comment: You are absolutely correct. I am very regretful and embarrassed to say the least to have misread the project specs the way I have.

Comment: @CSmizzle Almost always the reason for "I've translated this code from the other language but it doesn't work" type of questions on Stack Overflow is that the translated code doesn't look at *all* like the original. You should have written `parent` as a *function* in the C code too.

Comment: Yes, it has fixed all major issues. I am very gracious for the undeserving patience you have given me.